# How to append filename to a unified diff label

Tags: bash, diff, unified-diff

I am writing a bash script that needs to display a diff between a remote file and my local copy. I am doing this through a command:

```
filepath=/home/user/test.txt
ssh $REMOTE_USER cat $filepath | diff -bu --label="remote" --label="local" - $filepath
```

This generates something like:

```
--- remote
+++ local

@@ -2,7 +2,7 @@
--- This is a line
+++ This is something else
```

I would like to have the $filepath value included in the label but I don't know if this is possible or how to do it. Something like this:

```
--- remote /home/user/test.txt
+++ local /home/user/test.txt
@@ -2,7 +2,7 @@
--- This is a line
+++ This is something else
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 3):

This is what I get for posting while tired. I simply added $filepath to the --label option as in:

```
... --label="remote $filepath" --label="local $filepath"
```

Sheesh!

Comment: Since this is a typo sort of question and unlikely to help anyone in the future, I suggest that you delete the question.